# No student or no other students is as intelligent as my son

Tags: adjectives, negation

> [**no student** or **no other students**] is as intelligent as my son.

Why do we use "no other students" in the above sentence?

We do say that "There is no student in the class." Here "no student" refers to all the students which are not in the class.

So in the above sentence "no student" does not refer to all the students?

Answer (score 8):

*No X* means ‘not even one’ *X*: not a single member of the entire group *X*.

> No student in the class is 15 years old yet. ... *Of the students in the class, none is 15 years old; all of them are younger.*

*Other* divides the group you are talking about into two parts. You identify one of the parts, and what is left is the *other* part. For instance:

> The red books are mine. The other ones belong to Seema. ... *Here I am talking about a group of books. I identify one part, all the red books, as mine; everything that is left, the* other *ones, are yours.*
>
> Roy is the youngest boy in his class. He is 12; all the others are 13. ... *The group you are talking about is the boys in the class. One is named, Roy; the* others *are all the boys who are not Roy.*

So whenever you see the word *other* you have to identify what it is contrasted with.

In your sentence “No student is as intelligent as my son”, you are speaking about a group of students. If your son is a student, he is a member of that group, and the sentence contradicts itself: it is not true that ***no*** member of the group is as intelligent, because your son is a member and he is as intelligent as himself.

So you should say “no ***other*** student”. This divides the group into two parts: 1) your son, the most intelligent, and 2) all the ***other*** students who are not as intelligent as he is.

In this case you may cast *student* as either singular or plural; but as Martze says, whichever you choose, the verb must agree.

> No other student***s are*** as intelligent as my son.
> No other student ***is*** as intelligent as my son.

I prefer the singular, because I think of your son being compared to each other student individually; but the plural won't raise any eyebrows.

Comment: I got singular plural thing. But can you please make me understand the difference between no student and no other student. For me both makes the same sense. Thanks.

Comment: @SeemaBhukar See my rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

> No other student is as intelligent as my son.

*OR*

> No other students are as intelligent as my son.

Notice that student is the subject and both subject and predicate must have the same numerus.

I'd say, the word other emphasizes the fact that no other student is as smart. They both relate to the same group of people.

Comment: I would only got with The first alternative, because the second one violates the very rule you are stating.

Comment: Student and is are both singular, students and are are both plural. Do i miss somehing? If you know more, enlighten me please :)

Comment: That is correct, but I was referring to combining "No other student**s** **are**"(plural)  with "as intelligent as my *son*" (singular).

Comment: Please note that the OP asks about the *purpose* of the adjective **other**.

Comment: So "he eats two apples" would be wrong in your opinion? Both "apples" and "as my son" are not a subject.

Answer (score -1):

No student is as intelligent as my son. No girl is as beautiful as my daugther.  We use a question to identify the sentence subject: who is as intelligent as my son? Answer: No student. It means: No student( anyone, no another one student is as intelligent as my son). Grammar and Semantics as so as! That's all!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was 'no student' compared to 'no other students' and not about identifying the subject of the sentence.